# Magento2 Create simple Product programmatically only works once

Tags: magento2, product, simple-product, create-product

I have the following in our helper:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $option,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_prod = $product;
    $this->_option = $option;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function createProduct($sku, $name, $weight, $price, $jsonMix, $jsonPost, $type = 'simple')
{
    $mixProduct = $this->_productFactory->create();

    $mixProduct->setSku($sku); // Set your sku here
    $mixProduct->setName($name); // Name of Product
    $mixProduct->setWeight($weight); // weight of product
    $mixProduct->setPrice($price); // price of product
    $mixProduct->setDescription('' . $jsonMix . ' ' . $jsonPost);

    // defaults
    $mixProduct->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
    $mixProduct->setStatus(1); // enabled/ disabled 1/0
    $mixProduct->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
    $mixProduct->setTaxClassId(1); // Tax class id
    $mixProduct->setTypeId($type); // type of product
    $mixProduct->setWebsiteIds(array(1));

    $mixProduct->setStockData(
        array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
            'manage_stock' => 0,
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 1
        )
    );

    // now save the product
    try{
        $mixProduct->save();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    var_dump($mixProduct->getId()); die();

}
```

Calling it from a controller works only the first time, successfully creating a product in the backend.
But any subsequent tries seem to edit the already existing product instead of creating a new one.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you changed the SKU? Probably you are getting it updated because of that. Magento2 has a unique SKU per product.

Comment: I create the SKU using rand() at the moment for testing, so it should be unique.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was the Product name, which also has to be unique or at least differ from the previous product name.

Comment: Just add your answer to share it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Injecting `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` in the constructor means, you get the same instance every time (like a singleton).

That does not make sense for models. Instead you should inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` and then instantiate the product like this:

```
$product = this->productFactory->create();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my code. However, it still only creates one product, no matter how often I call the method. I use rand() to create the sku to prevent the same sku being submitted and it should return the id of the newly created product after being successfull.

Comment: So after some testing the problem seems to be the product Name - which also needs to be unique  -  so for testing I also just use rand(), now it works!